# binding integer value into the label

Tags: ios

I have to bind Json Data, data with string format is binding in the label ok, but I can't bind an integer or float value in the label. Is there any syntax for binding these types of values in a label?

```
        NSDictionary* info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                      showcost.text = [loans objectForKey:@"Cost"],
                      showname.text =  [loans objectForKey:@"Name"],nil];
```

I am getting the `Name`, but I can't bind the `Cost` (which the answer is 12.34). Please give me an idea to proceed.

Comment: How you are binding to UILabel, through code or through IB? And are you storing it in a Dictionary?

Comment: Iam binding through codes and  storing it in Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

For Integer values

```
int cost = [[loans objectForKey:@"Cost"]intValue];
showcost.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cost];
```

for float value

```
float cost = [[loans objectForKey:@"Cost"]floatValue];
showcost.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",cost];
```

Comment: You should not use string formats to show numbers to users. Instead, use NSNumberFormatter so the value if formatted properly for the user's locale.

Answer (score -1):

If cost is of float type, you could create a string value for it using stringWithFormat to print out Decimal floating point numbers as a string:

```
showcost.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [loans objectForKey:@"Cost"]];
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the property of the string literal as

```
showcost.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[loans objectForKey:@"Cost"]floatValue]];
```

Comment: This answer won't even compile since you are trying to assign a value of `float` to a property with a type of `NSString *`.